# How to force an initial value when creating a pipe with CurrentValueSubject in Combine in Swift 5?

Tags: ios, swift, swift5, combine

I am trying to fetch initial value of `EventDetailsModel` and subscribe to all future updates.

When I call `eventDetails(..)`, all the publishers already have some current value in them (i.e. `chatModels` and `userModels` have 10+ items); the problem is that because there are no new updates, the resulting pipe never returns `EventDetailModels` since `.map(...)` never gets called.

**How can I make the combine pipe do at least one pass through the existing values when I am constructing it so my sink has some initial value?**

```
var chatModels: Publishers.Share<CurrentValueSubject<[ChatModel], Never>> = CurrentValueSubject([]).share()
var userModels: CurrentValueSubject<[String: UserModel], Never> = CurrentValueSubject([:])

func eventDetails(forChatId chatId: String) -> AnyPublisher<EventDetailsModel?, Never> {
    return chatModels
        .combineLatest(userModels)
        .map({ (chatList, userModels) -> EventDetailsModel? in
            // Never gets called, even if chatModels and userModels has some existing data 
            if let chatModel = (chatList.first { $0.id == chatId}) {
                return EventDetailsModel(chatModel, userModels)
            }
            return nil
        })
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

Comment: It's the second question about roughly the same thing. Maybe, instead of asking how to make this specific thing work, broaden the question to describe what you're actually trying to achieve.

Comment: @NewDev Yes, it's probably an x-y question. My guess is that what the OP really wants is to use just `chatModels` as the publisher, followed by a `flatMap` that adds `userModels`. But without actual info about the goal, it's impossible to say.

Comment: @matt updated with higher level goal, pretty much I want to fetch an initial value and listen to subsequent updates. The problem is that I get subsequent updates, but not the initial value.

Comment: Ok, just noticed that `chatModels` is a `Publishers.Share`, I wonder if this changes the semantics.

Comment: You don't need `.share` for a subject. A subject is a reference-type anyway

Comment: Yeh, not sure why that was added there. Need to also look up what .share does.

Answer (score 1):

With `combineLatest`, you won't get any events until there *is* a latest for both publishers. That is what `combineLatest` *means*. The problem here is not `chatModels`, which *does* have a latest. The problem is `userModels`. Until it publishes for the first time, you won't get any events in this pipeline.

**EDIT** Okay, so now you've updated your code to reveal that *both* your publishers are CurrentValueSubjects. Well, in that case, you *do* get an initial event, as this toy example proves:

```
var storage = Set<AnyCancellable>()
let sub1 = CurrentValueSubject<Int,Never>(1)
let sub2 = CurrentValueSubject<String,Never>("howdy")
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    sub1.combineLatest(sub2)
}
```

So if that isn't happening for you, the problem lies elsewhere. For example, maybe you forgot to `store` your pipeline, so you can't get any events at all. (But who knows? You have concealed the relevant code.)

Comment: Updated my question to indicate that both `userModels` and `chatModels` are initialized with some data. My intuition here is that unless there are future events emitted, the `.map()` won't get called with the current setup, regardless of initial data.

Comment: Well, I assure you that if you really have two CurrentValueSubjects and you make a CombineLatest out of them, you _do_ get an event. So the problem must lie elsewhere. But who knows? You keep hiding your code from us.

Comment: I am not hiding code. I just want to simplify since if I add my codebase, it becomes harder to read. I am sure you understand that much.

Comment: No, I don't. For example, you refer to a `sink`. But there _is_ no sink. Yet you still expect us to be able to help you? Moreover, I have shown _you_ enough code to show what _does_ work. But you have not shown enough code to reproduce what _doesn't_ work. I am sure you understand what a [mcve] is.

Comment: I was thinking of adding sink there, but thought it's fairly self-evident what it does ‍♂️. Found out it's from having chatModel wrapped in `Publishers.Share`, not sure why that was done. Switching both to be `CurrentValueSubject` works, as you mentioned above.

Comment: A Subject is already a class and doesn't need `share`. — Oh, I see that New Dev already mentioned that.